# childNodes is 0 but I have children

Tags: javascript, html, removechild, htmlcollection

I have the following HTML. Using JS, I have a HTMLcollection of slot. And then I am trying to remove the child `<p>` for a given slot. But the JS console is throwing an error that there is no child. Is it because I have a HTMLCollection?

```js
const slots = document.getElementsByClassName('slot');

for (let i = 0; i < slots.length; i++) {
  slots[i].addEventListener('dragover', () => {
    const dragging = document.querySelector('.card-dragging');
    slots[i].appendChild(dragging);
    slots[i].removeChild(slots[i].lastChild);
  })
};
```

```html
<section class="slots">
  <div class="slot">
    <img id="rabbit" src="https://gravatar.com/avatar/c331326b84b173e6fb0ddaefd8520044?s=400&d=retro&r=x" alt="rabbit" />
    <p class="card-slot card-temp"></p>
  </div>

  <div class="slot">
    <img id="ball" src="https://gravatar.com/avatar/c331326b84b173e6fb0ddaefd8520044?s=400&d=retro&r=x" alt="ball" />
    <p class="card-slot card-temp"></p>
  </div>

  <div class="slot">
    <img id="book" src="https://gravatar.com/avatar/c331326b84b173e6fb0ddaefd8520044?s=400&d=retro&r=x" alt="book" />
    <p class="card-slot card-temp"></p>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: I getting a completely different error message, what are you actually trying to achieve with your script?

Comment: When I drag and drop something in this <div>, I want to remove this <p> and append a new one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code can benefit from Delegation

You cannot remove the child in the middle of dragging, I expect you want to hide and move it back outside when you drop?

I could not find the `.card-dragging` so I guessed

```js
const slots = document.querySelector('.slots');
slots.addEventListener('dragover', (e) => {
  const tgt = e.target.closest('div.slot');
  if (!tgt) return;
  const dragging = document.querySelector('.card-dragging');
  tgt.appendChild(dragging);
})
```

```css
img {
  height: 50px;
}

.slot { border: 1px solid black; }
```

```html
<section class="slots">
  <div class="slot">
    <img id="rabbit" src="https://gravatar.com/avatar/c331326b84b173e6fb0ddaefd8520044?s=400&d=retro&r=x" alt="rabbit" />
    <p class="card-slot card-temp"></p>
  </div>

  <div class="slot">
    <img id="ball" src="https://gravatar.com/avatar/c331326b84b173e6fb0ddaefd8520044?s=400&d=retro&r=x" alt="ball" />
    <p class="card-slot card-temp"></p>
  </div>

  <div class="slot">
    <img id="book" src="https://gravatar.com/avatar/c331326b84b173e6fb0ddaefd8520044?s=400&d=retro&r=x" alt="book" />
    <p class="card-slot card-temp"></p>
  </div>
</section>
<div class="card-dragging">Drop?</div>
```

Comment: This works perfectly thank you. 

Can you just explain what you mean by "You cannot remove the child in the middle of dragging"? Because it looks like you're doing the same thing?

Comment: `slots[i].removeChild(slots[i].lastChild);` gave errors because it was still needed - I am not `removing` anything